# What's the difference between :D and :D:?

Tags: raku

I was browsing the [Perl 6 docs on the `shift` routine](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/shift) and saw this snippet:

> Defined as:
>
> ```
> multi sub    shift(Array:D )
> multi method shift(Array:D:)
> ```

I know `:D` means the `Array` is `defined` and not `Any` or `Nil`, but what's `:D:`? It's very hard to search for.

[This section](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#___top) of the type signature docs contains more examples of the syntax, but does not (as far as I can tell) explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christoph's answer is already excellent. My answer is an attempt to provide some context with a small concrete example.

As Christoph states, in Raku the invocant of a method gets passed as an implicit first positional argument which is then available to the method's body as `self`:

```
class Person {
    has $.name;
    
    method greet( Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
        self.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
    }
}

my $john = Person.new(name => 'John');
my $dana = Person.new(name => 'Dana');
say $john.greet($dana, 'Good morning'); # «John: Good morning, Dana.»
```

If you wish to bind it to something else, then use the syntax `method meth-name( invocant : param1, param2, ..., param3) { ... }`  where `param1, param2, ..., param3` are the regular parameters (both positional and named ones) you declare in a method. As Christoph states, this syntax "is necessary even in case of [a paratemer-less signature] so it can be disambiguated from a signature with a regular positional parameter." Therefore:

```
# Person A greets person B.
method greet( $A : Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    $A.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

You could go a step further and also type the invocant, not necessarily because it's needed but because it makes the method's signature more descriptive:

```
# Person A greets person B.
method greet( Person $A : Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    $A.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

If you don't want the method `greet` to accepts type objects (e.g., `Person`) but instead only objects instance of the type (e.g., `Person.new`), then you can make use of the *type
smily* `:D`.  Thus:

```
# Person A greets person B.
method greet( Person:D $A : Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    $A.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

The [type smilies](https://docs.raku.or/type/Signature#Constraining_argument_definiteness) are `:D` (for **D**efined), `:U` (for **U**ndefined), and `:_` (this is the implicit smily for a type that uses neither `:D` nor `:U`).

If you remove the explicit invocant (and revert to using `self`) from the method's signature, then you'll end up with something similar to what you have in your question. Here I'm just using some whitespace to make it look less daunting:

```
method greet( Person:D : Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    self.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

---

**Addendum:**

In Raku, methods can be restricted to either be called only on a class's object instances (for *object methods*) or only on the class itself (for *class methods*); you just need to add the `:D` smily to the class name for object methods and  the `:U` smily to the class name for class methods:

```
method object-method( CLASSNAME:D : ) { ... }
method class-method( CLASSNAME:U : ) { ... }
```

However, this isn't as general as could be so instead, you can use the compile-time variable [`::?CLASS`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-::%3FCLASS) which determines the current class and thus do away with the need for putting the name of the class there. For example, to restrict `greet` to only be called on instance objects of `Person`:

```
method greet( ::?CLASS:D: Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    self.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

Like always if you're confused by the colons, you can always put some whitespace between whatever thing a type smily is attached to and the remaining `:` to make things more obvious, as in:

```
method greet( ::?CLASS:D : Person $B, $greeting = 'Hello' ) {
    self.name ~ ": $greeting, " ~ $B.name ~ '.'
}
```

Comment: Great answer, the second code block says `self.name` but should probably say `$A.name` as `self` is not bound

Comment: I would point out that `::?CLASS` is there so that you don't have to put the name of the class there. (Which also works.)

Comment: @cat Thanks for pointing that out; I've corrected it. @BradGilbert I've pointed out why `::?CLASS` is there. BTW, feel free to edit the answer if you think it could be further improved ;-). Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

The invocant of a method gets passed as an implicit first argument. If you want to use an explicit parameter within the signature (eg to add a type smiley like `:D` or just to give it a more descriptive name), you need to separate it with a `:` instead of a `,` from the rest of the parameter list. This is necessary even in case of an empty list so it can be disambiguated from a signature with a regular positional parameter.

Some more information can be found [in the design documents](http://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Invocant_parameters).